# Permission levels for a tab

Tags: java, php, html, database, permissions

I know this sounds like a pretty simple question but I want to make sure that I am going about this in the right way before I begin coding. I am trying to hardcode a tab for a standard website (I don't want to use any other software/programs if possible) that is visible to all users but can only be accessed by people with certain permision levels aka admins. I am getting all my user information from a database file (lets call it users.txt) that is set up/contains the following: -username  -password  -permission level. So here is my thought proccess on this so far: grab each full line from the database, if(permission level != 1) then(alert message pops up and brings user back to home page).

So here is my questions:
-First off is this even the right way to go about this?
-How do I get a full line from the database and store the info in created variables? I want to try and get the info from the DB line by line, and store them in temp variables and see if the user logged in matches that information. (I guess this would go first when the user logs in and store the permission level info for later use aka when they try to access this tab).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good idea. Firstly I would recommend using an actual database, e.g. SQLite. I also think storing user permissions in a file is a particularly poor way of ensuring security (as the user can just edit the file). Using a real database will allow you to extract the users permission directly from the database without having to search. Furthermore depending on the database you chose you may be able to use various integrity features for security.

I would recommend, that you put the information in a database, then use the logged in user's information to pull the correct permissions level, and if it is high enough load the tab. Depending on your security needs you can also enforce some kind of integrity checks on the database and loading the tab from an external source (although in reality you would keep the tab's code encrypted on the device and requisition the key from a central authority).

Comment: The database file will already be created and I won't have to worry about users changing the file because only admins have permission to view/edit this file already. I'm just having trouble grabing the lines from the database file. I would assume to put the 'get line from db code' in a for loop so it will go through the entire file

Comment: Hmm, I would still recommend using a proper database, an SQLite database is also just a file, and will be much easier and faster than implementing your own database software. A real database will also give you far better performance on this kind of search.

Comment: I might have not made my question clear so I edit it, but this isn't for a database; it's a tab for a website. Luckily I won't have to worry about the database part, I just have to get my information from the db.